# Start and stop interval using button [as3]

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I tried to make two buttons, one that starts an interval and one that stops it.
This is my code:

```
s_start.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startRepeater);
s_stop.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopRepeater);

function startRepeater(e:MouseEvent) : void {
setInterval(repeater,500);
}

function stopRepeater(e:MouseEvent) : void {
clearInterval(repeater);
}
```

The start button works perfectly! but the stop button doesn't.
1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Function to an unrelated type uint.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You have a correct answer. Please use the big "correct" tick to mark this question as solved & to show thanks.

Comment: Why did I get a -1 on this post lol

Comment: Doesn't make sense so I've done a cancelling +1. I suspect that since coders who write programs to **spam** are not nice people, maybe that's why you got a random negative reaction?...

Comment: Thank you :P Well, it was not intended to harm someone, just to "spam" the function. Maybe I should have called it repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clearInterval function accepts an unsigned integer which is an id to the interval you created not a function. Check out this **[tutorial](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3setinterval/)** for more info.

So you might want to try something like this

```
var intervalId:uint;

s_start.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startspam);
function startspam(e:MouseEvent):void {
    intervalId = setInterval(spam,500);
}

s_stop.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopspam);
function stopspam(e:MouseEvent):void {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
}
```

Comment: No need for assumptions. The `spam` function is running every 500 ms for sure. Otherwise this is a correct answer.

Comment: spam was never defined in his code snipped that's why i mentioned it but yea good point another error would have occurred if it wasn't a function.